# Binding with @Autowired not working inside instances initiated with 'new'

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

In my web spring application I create an instance with key word `new`  as following.
In my one of action class, following method exists.

```
public void process() { 

    MyBean b=new MyBean(); //initiated the instance with new  
    b.process();
}
```

Other MyBean class

```
@Service
public class MyBean {  

@Autowired  
MyService service;  

public void process() { 
    service.execute(); // this service instance has not initialized by Spring DI :( .service object is null. 
}
```

the MyService instance is not set by spring Dependency injection. Is it because that I create the instance of MyBean myself with `new` not the Spring ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my Spring @Autowired field null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null)

Answer (score 6):

If you want to autowire programmatically, you can use:

```
private @Autowired AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory;

public void process() {
   MyBean obj = new MyBean();
   beanFactory.autowireBean(obj);
   // obj will now have its dependencies autowired.
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes. It is not being set by DI of Spring as the instance you created using new keyword is not being managed by Spring container. Spring will by default inject dependencies only for spring managed instances. So to resolve this problem you can do it by two ways. First is don't use the `new` and use `@Autowired` on `Mybean` instance.

Second is to use `@Configurable` on `MyBean` class. With the `@Configurable` annotation spring will inject dependencies even for objects created through `new` keyword. Remember to have `AspectJ` jars on your classpath with `@configurable` annotation as Spring need them to inject Dependecies.

For the second approach use `@Configurable(preConstruction = true)` and add the following dependencies to your pom.xml

```
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
<version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
<artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
<version>1.6.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
<artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
<version>1.6.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
<artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
<version>1.6.8</version>
</dependency>
```

You also need to compile it through AspectJ Compiler so that Byte code generated has the required abilities. You should use the following entries to make sure system using AspectJ Compiler at compile time.

```
<build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.4</version>
<configuration>
<showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
<source>1.6</source>
<target>1.6</target>
<Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
<complianceLevel>1.6</complianceLevel>
<encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
<verbose>false</verbose>
<aspectLibraries>
<aspectLibrary>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
</aspectLibrary>
</aspectLibraries>
</configuration>
<executions>
<execution>
<goals>
<goal>compile</goal>
<goal>test-compile</goal>
</goals>
</execution>
</executions>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
<artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
<version>1.6.8</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
<artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
<version>1.6.11</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You mean    `<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
 <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
` only this enough?

Answer (score 3):

When you create an object by new, autowire\inject don't work...

as workaround you can try this:

create your template bean of MyBean

```
<bean id="myBean" class="..." scope="prototype">
    <!-- collaborators and configuration for this bean go here -->
</bean>
```

and create an istance in this way

```
context.getBean("myBean");
```

**PROTOTYPE :** This scopes a single bean definition to have any number of object instances.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, spring does not recognize `MyBean` bean because you are creating it with `new` operator. Let spring initialize this bean and then you can have autowired beans accessed inside `MyBean`. For e.g.

```
<bean id="myBean" class="your.package.MyBean"></bean>
```

Above entry in your application context will create `MyBean` in spring container. And using this object you can access the services written inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution can be the use of `@Component` like this:

```
@Component("myBean")
public class MyBean{  

    @Autowired  
    MyService service;  

    public void process(){ 

    service.execute(); // this service instance has not initialized by Spring DI :( .service object is null. 

    }
}
```

And at your class where `process()` is, you can Autowire like this:

```
@Autowired
MyBean b

public void process(){  


  b.process();


}
```